# Error while building rt73-k2wrlz-3.0.3 from source

Tags: 11.10, installation, wireless, package-management, install-from-source

I've already install the build-essential package but it doesn't work
that's right i'm trying to compile a wireless driver i'm trying to use aircrack-ng so i need to patch the driver of my wireless adapter 
it's supposed to work typing the followings lines 
tar xfj rt73-k2wrlz-1.3.0.tar.bz2
cd rt73-k2wrlz-1.3.0/Module
make
make install

```
cristian@Cristian-pc:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for cristian: 
root@Cristian-pc:/home/cristian# cd Downloads
root@Cristian-pc:/home/cristian/Downloads# cd rt73-k2wrlz-3.0.3/Module
root@Cristian-pc:/home/cristian/Downloads/rt73-k2wrlz-3.0.3/Module# make
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 0 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic'
rt73.ko failed to build!
make: *** [module] Error 1
root@Cristian-pc:/home/cristian/Downloads/rt73-k2wrlz-3.0.3/Module#
```

Comment: There is no way to tell. A tar.bz2 is an archive with something inside, and you have to know what that is. Sometimes, it's source code with the README file telling you what to do, othertimes, it's a bunch of binary files that don't require installation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install a .tar.gz file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-file)

Comment: that's right i'm trying to compile a wireless driver i'm trying to use aircrack-ng so i need to patch the driver of my wireless adapter it's supposed to work typing the followings lines      tar xfj rt73-k2wrlz-1.3.0.tar.bz2                                cd rt73-k2wrlz-1.3.0/Module                                    make                                                           make install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need that patch, it is for much older kernels.

> according to aircrack-ng.org: "This fix is already included in 2.6.31 and newer kernels, so this patch should only be used up to 2.6.30."

See posts #49 and #50 on this thread

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1215251

Relevant excerpts posted below

Post 49

> whoopsy, I guess you can inject with rt73usb right out of the box!
>
> I simply used airmon-ng after install "iw"

```
sudo apt-get install iw
airmon-ng start <device>
```

Post 50

> This tutorial only dealt with the legacy ieee80211 version of the RT73 driver (p_larbig/ASPj mods), hence why we needed to blacklist the mac80211 driver version.
>
> The driver bundled with karmic is the mac80211 based one (which depends on rt2x00usb & rt2x00lib). That's why you needed to install the tool "IW" (needed for stacks-mac80211 interface management)
>
> To understand the differences, see [mac80211 versus ieee80211 stacks write-up](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_drivers#mac80211_versus_ieee80211_stacks).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the drivers are already installed.

Open a terminal and try this command:

```
sudo modprobe rt73usb
```

then this:

```
iwconfig
```

Do you now have a wireless interface?